# CIVIEVENT: Templates are saving as events

Tags: civievent, templates

I am on CIVICRM 5.46.3.  I have saved event templates successfully in the past.  Now when I add a new event template, it saves it as an event versus a template.  I have created and deleted one several times (making sure the title of the page says template) and it still saves as an event versus a template.  Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you replicate this on one of the 'master' sites, and if not, report back on any differences you were able to identify https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: I have the same problem and no idea to solve it.
CiviCRM 5.58.1. with WordPress 6.2.2

Comment: Can you replicate this on one of the 'master' sites, and if not, report back on any differences you were able to identify dmaster.demo.civicrm.org